# Is there a clean continuation line in C++ similar to C# @"Text" or Python """Text"""?

Tags: c++

For example, **for copy/paste purposes**, it is very convenient to write :

## C#

```
@"
SELECT * FROM ......
WHERE X = (SELECT Y FROM .....)
    AND M IN ('1','2','3')
";
```

or

## Python:

```
"""
SELECT * FROM ......
WHERE X = (SELECT Y FROM .....)
    AND M IN ('1','2','3')
"""
```

than:

## C++

```
"SELECT * FROM ...... \
WHERE X = (SELECT Y FROM .....) \
    AND M IN ('1','2','3')"
```

Is there any way to avoid the \ style in C++ and approach to C# or python style?

Thanks.

Comment: Raw SQL literals are always a bad idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to delimit strings in C++ like PHP's Heredoc Syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348847/is-there-a-way-to-delimit-strings-in-c-like-phps-heredoc-syntax)

Comment: By the answers and recommendations I received, -and thanks for that!- it seems to be impossible for C++ to emulate the C# or python styles such as I described. :-(

Comment: @Tristan: In C++11 there are raw string literals which you can use. However, I don't know what compiler you are using as not all compilers support it.

Comment: Another dupe - with a raw string literal example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5460235/8331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think C++11 allows newlines in raw string literals, e.g.:

```
const char *query = R"(SELECT * FROM ...... 
                       WHERE X = (SELECT Y FROM .....) 
                       AND M IN ('1','2','3'))";
```

Each newline in the source should result in a newline in the execution string-literal. Raw string literals generally take the form of `R"( ... )"`. For GCC this requires at least version 4.5, and for clang++, it requires version 3.0. Alternatively, you can use a custom delimiter to make it easier to disambiguate the end of the string:

```
const char *query = R"XXXX(SELECT * FROM ...... 
                       WHERE X = (SELECT Y FROM .....) 
                       AND M IN ('1','2','3'))XXXX";
```

Answer (score 3):

C++ (as well as C) automatically concatenates adjacent string literals. There's no need for `\` with string literals. E.g. this

```
const char *p = "Hello" "World"   
  "!";
```

is equivalent to

```
const char *p = "HelloWorld!";
```

In your case you can simply do

```
"SELECT * FROM ...... "
"WHERE X = (SELECT Y FROM .....) "
"    AND M IN ('1','2','3')"
```

and the result will be equivalent to your original version with `\`, i.e. one continuous string literal will be produced.

This does not insert linebreaks or any other additional whitespace between the concatenated segments though. You have to remember to do it yourself, if you need something like that.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, the problem here (in this case) is that I can not copy/paste the sql command and to inmediately execute it, I must first delete the intermediate quotes. That was the spirit of my question.

Comment: It would be hard to argue that this way is somehow better than using backslashes: instead of one extra character at the end you must now add two characters. But I guess it does count as a *different* way of doing it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: at least you don't have to make sure the backslash ist the last character on the line --

Comment: @Tristan: Yeah... If you are looking for a way to just paste a block of text without having to do any per-line post-processing, then no, standard C++ does not have anything suitable.

Comment: @AndreyT: It depends on which version of the standard you are using. C++11 introduces raw string literals which allow newlines.